# Can't run PHPUnit as it says "PHPUnit requires PHP 5.6", but I have 4.2 installed

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, vagrant, composer-php

I've been stuck on this for around 4hrs now. I'm trying to run some tests on my Laravel 5 project. They worked a month or so ago when I ran them last, but I'm wanting to run them again. Just FYI, I'm using Vagrant.

Here's a snippet from my composer.json file.

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "illuminate/html": "^5.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.0.0",
    "zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5",
    "kalnoy/nestedset": "^3.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.2.*",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
```

But whenever I run phpunit through the terminal, it states

> This version of PHPUnit requires PHP 5.6; using the latest version of PHP is highly recommended.

I've tried the below - all found via Google and Stack Overflow.

- the `composer clear-cache` command
- reloading vagrant
- changing versions (4.0, ~4.0, 4.8, 4.1.*)
- adding *"cache-files-ttl": 0* to my composer.json

Entering in the below all return the same error message about PHP 5.6

- *phpunit --check-version*
- *phpunit --self-update*
- *phpunit*

For what it's worth, `/vendor/phpunit/composer.json` shows

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    ...
}
...
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "4.2.x-dev"
    }
},
```

Also, calling `php -v` shows "PHP 5.4.45 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2015 15:40:44)". `phpinfo()` shows the same thing.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Assuming you're on Linux or a Mac, try running `which phpunit`. It's likely you have more than one copy bouncing around.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry - running mac. *which phpunit* returns "/usr/bin/phpunit"... aaah - which would be why it's not finding my /vendor/phpunit !?

Comment: Okay, seems I can execute the vendor version via *"./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit"*. Thanks for the tip @EdCottrell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more than one copy of phpunit on your system. Running this command in a terminal will tell you which one is in your path:

```
which phpunit
```

As your comments above confirmed, you weren't using the one in your project folder, so you'll need to start phpunit with

```
./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit [rest of command]
```

or create a symlink to that copy.